# Adding attachment to Gmail url

Tags: url, gmail, attachment

We're using the following URL to open an empty mail from our Destop application : 
https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=email@gmail.com

So an empty mail is opened and 'to'-adress is filled in.  But is there a way to also attach an attachment using an URL ?
Something like :
https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=email@gmail.com&attachment=myfile.pdf

Kind regards
Bart S.